# ADF Error logs in Storage container are empty

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a datapipeline using Azure storage blob as source and postgressql as a sink. There are assert validations in place and i want to log the failed asserts to a blob apart from allowing them to write to the sink.

On completion i am getting two files in the errors container but both are empty. I have tried running in debug as well as published mode with same results..
[image: The empty blog]
[image: the mapping settings]

I expected the logs to have the faulted rows. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the above and got same results.

[image]

This happens when you left the `Assert description` empty. Provide some message in the `Assert description` to get the files.

[image]

**My Assert output:**

[image]

**Error log files:**

[image]